# Extreme of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Let us have the following function on $x\in[0,1]$
$$
y =f(x)= x + a\left(\max(0,b-x)\right)
$$
where $a>0$ and $b\in[0,1]$ are known parameters. Could you please find the solution of this
$$
x^{*}=\arg \min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)
$$
please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case $a\le 1$: For $x<b$, $f(x)=x+a(b-x) = ab+x(1-a)$, which is a monotonously non-decreasing. For $x\ge b$, $f(x) = x$, which is a monotonously increasing function. And since $f(b-\epsilon) = ab+(b-\epsilon)(1-a) = b - \epsilon+a\epsilon$ and $f(b+\epsilon) = b+\epsilon$, it is continuous, indicating $x^*=0$.

Case $a>1$: For $x<b$, $y=x+a(b-x) = ab+x(1-a)$, which is a monotonously non-increasing. For $x\ge b$, $f(x) = x$, which is a monotonously increasing function. Like in the above case, it is easy to see that it is continuous. So, $x^*=b$.